# OWASP (zap) にてURLエンコードされていないパラメーターを持つURLにアクセスしたい

Tags: javascript, java, xss

### 概要

構築しているサイトの脆弱性を発見したく、OWASP(zap) D-2017-02-27を利用しています。
URLエンコーディングされていないURLへアクセスを行い、XSSが発生していないか確認したいと考えています。
OWSPの規定のxssの動作では検出できない、特定のパラメーターを持つアクセスを行いたいと考え、ActiveRulesへJavaScriptを追加しましたが、パラメーターの値がURLエンコードされてしまい、XSSが発生しません。IE11では同等のアクセスを行うとXSSが発生することを確認できているので、これをOWASPで検知したいと考えています。Java/JavaScriptの知識が浅く、困っております。
お助けください。

### 対象URL例

```
http://localhost/app/index.html?cc=aaa
```

に対し、

```
http://localhost/app/index.html?cc=aaa>"><script>alert(1)</script>
```

というアクセスを発生させたい。

### ActiveRules

```
uri = msg.getRequestHeader().getURI();
query = uri.getQuery() + '>"><script>alert(1)</script>';
uri.setQuery(query);
```

uriを作成している時点で私のつたないJava/JavaScriptの知識だとパラメーター等がURLエンコードされてしまうとおもうのですが、URLエンコードせずにアクセスする方法はないでしょうか？
new URIの部分で第２引数をtrueにするとスクリプトが落ちてしまいます。

### 上記コードを走らせた場合のOWASP上のURL表示

```
https://localhost/app/index.html?cc=aaa%3E%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(1)%3C/script%3E
```

以上です。ご教授のほど、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

### 追記

コードをリファクタし、再掲しました。
uriのクラスを下記コードで調べたところ、`org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI` でした。

```
println(uri.getClass());
```

Answer (score 0):

uri.setQuery(query);
　　↓
uri.setEscapedQuery(query);

でうまくいかないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。試してみたところ、
    class org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI
    java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableExceptionsun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.WrappedException: Wrapped     org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException: escaped query not valid (<Unknown source>#41) in <Unknown source> at line number 41
というエラーとなりました。

Comment: うーん。では、setRawQueryだとどうなりますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
同様にエラーですね。。

Comment: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableExceptionsun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Can't find method org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.setRawQuery(string). (<Unknown source>#42) in <Unknown source> at line number 42

Comment: エラー内容はそんなメソッドないよ！という感じになりました。

Comment: 失礼しました。setRawQueryのパラメータはchar[]でした...

public void setRawQuery(char[] escapedQuery)

Comment: uri = msg.getRequestHeader().getURI();
の後に、以下を追加してURLの値を確認したら、どうなるでしょうか？
println(uri.getQuery());
println(uri.getEscapedQuery());

Comment: scan called for url=https://localhost/xxxxx/xxxx.html?xxxx=yyyyy    
    
    uri.getQuery: xxxx=yyyyy     
    uri.getEscapedQuery: xxxx=yyyy

Comment: 少し時間があったので、[英語版](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663960/owaspzapxssi-want-detect-xss-via-owaspwhen-i-use-ie11-xss-happen)の方に質問にあったスクリプトを実際にOWASP ZAPで動かしながら、試してみましたが、いい方法が見つかりませんでした...


org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIにURLエンコードされないURLを渡しても、内部的にURLエンコードされてしまうようで、意図した通りに動きませんね。

すいません、お力になれず。

Comment: 調べていただいてありがとうございますございます。やはり難しいようですね。。私の方もソース落として確認してみましたが同じ結論になりました。